# What’s the longest amount of time that a can of soda could stay fresh?

Tags: food, chemistry

In the fallout series, people are often seen drinking Nuka-Cola, a rip-off of Coke. The earliest fallout game is 80 years after the war, the latest was 210 years.
So how the hell could soda last that long without refrigeration. In the games, they explain it by saying that the Cola is packed with preservatives to keep it fresh, but I don’t by it. How could you make a soda the lasts 200 years+?

Edit: I mean how could the soda taste the same

Comment: Its not soda... its Nuka-Cola!

Comment: If you flash freezed it and then vacuum sealed it . It would last a long time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as duplicate because the same ueation was asked on Cooking.SE https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5897/how-long-does-unopened-room-temperature-pop-last

Comment: @RonJohn i dont think its a duplicate as they are widely different . Op here asks about how one could store nuka cola a fictional drink for a long time .while in cooking SE its more about finding how long a real life bottle might last

Comment: @TheIntegrator then it should be closed as Primarily Opinion Based.

Comment: @RonJohn: No, it shouldn’t

Comment: Gotta agree with RonJon. Either we base this off real world properties of drinks and this is a duplicate or it’s a trivial question because you can just say ‘pack it full of preservative Unobtanium-D to keep it fresh and glowy!’

Comment: Now, if you’re asking how to keep it *fizzy* for as long as possible: that’s a different question.

Comment: &Joe Bloggs: No, fizziness is not a requirement. Not-Givin-You-Diarrhea-Ness is, though

Comment: I’ve voted to close because the linked question on cooking se covers pretty much everything you need to know about long term beverage freshness, and that includes not being killed by said beverage.

Comment: I don't think the title asks a good question that can be answered. I like the one in the actual body much better. Btw, fizziness is somewhat trivial to do, just have the same pressure and partial pressure of co2 inside and outside the bottle. Btw, some inspiration, even though not the exact same scenario: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJiUWBiM8HE

Comment: @Joe Bloggs: I have a better idea. What if you don’t vote to close my question

Comment: @RonJohn I didn't think closing questions as dupes of another site's question was a thing.

Comment: @Talos2 I’m just calling it as I see it. There’s nothing here that suggests Worldbuilding to me aside from the use of a fictional brand name, and the question on this exact topic on cooking SE covers what you need to know about freshness (ie: it’s not a problem if you don’t break the container and don’t mind the taste). If you mean ‘how can I keep it tasting the same for 80 years’ then that would be a different question (though I still think it’s a better fit for cooking than World-building)

Comment: @Bellerophon you're right.  That's why my VTC is registered as Off Topic, not Duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a question about world building, there is another aspect of cola storage that is worth considering. Aluminium cans will react freely with electromagnetic radiation, including light, heat, and obviously the fallout of nuclear radiation. So, unless you you happened to keep a large supply of cola in a cool lead-lined underground bunker for 80 years, you'd end up with bigger problems than whether or not your soda was flat.

Having said that, cola syrup isn't especially hard to make. [Open Cola](https://cube-cola.org/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=10) is a thing. You'd be better off storing large quantities of syrup in said lead-lined underground bunker, and carbonating it in small batches from there. Hardly a post-apocalyptic survival priority, but, hey, if there's leftover orange oil from somewhere, why not?